# Elasticsearch Geo Distance Sorting

Tags: elasticsearch

Refering to the documentation of [Sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/search-request-sort.html), section Geo Distance Sorting, here's the question:

The given example is as follows:

```
GET /_search
{
    "sort" : [
        {
            "_geo_distance" : {
                "pin.location" : [-70, 40],
                "order" : "asc",
                "unit" : "km",
                "mode" : "min",
                "distance_type" : "sloppy_arc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

Is `pin.location` the field in the mapping containing the geo location? Or is it a keyword understood by the search API as including the base location? If it's a field supposedly containing the location, shouldn't the sort term include the `nested_path` set to `pin`? And if it's a parameter, where does elasticsearch fetch the location of the item from?

Also, the documentaion mentions `sort_mode` as a parameter, but the code uses `mode`, I suppose that's a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pin.location` is the name of field containing the location to sort against.

`nested_path` is not needed if `pin` is a simple object, i.e. not a `nested` one.

Both `mode` and `sort_mode` are correct names, however, `sort_mode` is deprecated, so `mode` should be preferred.